# Activeweb/ActiveJDBC with C3P0 database connections

Tags: datasource, c3p0, activejdbc, javalite, activeweb

I'm attempting to get an ActiveWeb/ActiveJDBC connection configured to use C3P0 for connection pooling.

I know the documentation provided by Javalite says each transaction will be a single opened/closed connection, but does also mentions we can open a datasource via:

```
new DB("default").open( cpds );
```

This leads me to think it might be possible to intercept the connection open/close mechanism by including on AppControllerConfig:

```
addGlobalFilters( new DBConnectionFilterTest("default", true)  );
```

... where DBConnectionFilterTest is a custom class extending DBConnectionFilter that overrides the before/after behavior that opens and closes the connection.  The Datasource is configured within the constructor using a ComboPooledDataSource.

I was curious if anyone had any insight on this configuration, or have been successful in integrating C3P0 to activeweb/activeJDBC?

The furthest I have gotten so far is to get C3P0 to fire up.  I see the 5 connections in my session monitor, but activeweb still initiates a new connection when performing a transaction.  The C3P0 pool hasn't moved.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing your own filter to open and close a connection, do not forget to close a connection after a request is completed. This will return the connection back to the pool. 
Check out [DBConnectionFilter](https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/blob/master/activeweb/src/main/java/org/javalite/activeweb/controller_filters/DBConnectionFilter.java) code, specifically methods `onException()` and `after()`. If for some reason you will not close a connection, ActiveWeb will attempt to close it for you, but will complain in the log.

Personally, I use a built-in pool from Tomcat. It performs without any issues in production environments under a heavy load. A standard implementation of `DBConnectionFilter` does it then.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I'm using Jetty and so far it is doing quite well without further implementation of C3P0.  I've thrown a lot of load test at it, and Jetty/Activeweb handles it 100%.